# qbfc passing additional data when creating an invoice

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

When creating a new invoice how can I pass additional data for the invoice.

```
            invoiceAdditionalData.DataExtName.SetValue("PO/SA#");
            invoiceAdditionalData.DataExtValue.SetValue("a unique number for this invoice");
            invoiceAdditionalData.OwnerID.SetValue("0");
            invoiceAdditionalData.ORListTxn.ListDataExt.ListDataExtType.SetValue(ENListDataExtType.ldetCustomer);
            invoiceAdditionalData.ORListTxn.ListDataExt.ListObjRef.FullName.SetValue(invoiceAdd.CustomerRef.FullName.GetValue());
```

The code above always changes the customers additional data, so all existing invoices get the new value. How do I tell the QBFC that this additional data is for the invoice and not for the customer.
**EDIT: Working version**

```
            IDataExtAdd invoiceAdditionalData = requestMsgSet.AppendDataExtAddRq();
            invoiceAdditionalData.DataExtName.SetValue("PO/SA#");
            invoiceAdditionalData.DataExtValue.SetValue("the id");
            invoiceAdditionalData.OwnerID.SetValue("0");

            invoiceAdd.defMacro.SetValue("TxnID:" + invoiceNo);

                            invoiceAdditionalData.ORListTxnWithMacro.TxnDataExtWithMacro.TxnDataExtType.SetValue(ENTxnDataExtType.tdetInvoice);
            invoiceAdditionalData.ORListTxnWithMacro.TxnDataExtWithMacro.TxnID.SetValueUseMacro("TxnID:" + invoiceNo);
```

Comment: the above solution did not seem to be working it was always putting in the same data, it started working after I cleared the custom data value on the customer record itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last 2 lines you're telling it to update the customer, not the invoice. Instead of ListDataExt, use TxnDataExtWithMacro (for DataExtAdd - you don't need a macro) or TxnDataExt (for DataExtMod). The specify tdetInvoice as the type in line 4, and give it the Invoice's TxnID in line 5.